# Como usar esse Modal bootstrap de forma mais elegante?

Tags: jquery, modal, bootstrap-4

Não sei se o titulo é adequado, mas vou explicar:

No exemplo abaixo tenho um modal de confirmação que pode ser chamado por vários botões e dependendo do botão clicado tomo uma atitude.

Estou usando uma variável global para saber qual botão foi clicado, mas estou pensando que essa não é uma forma segura pois se esse código crescer posso ter problemas.

Eu não manjo muito de jQuery a ponto de fazer Callbacks e também não sei se esse seria o caso, estou pensando se seria possível transferir o botão clicado para o evento Onclick do objeto button de uma forma mais elegante (ou adequada).

Talvez a minha ideia esteja totalmente fora do que seria recomendado, mas procurando na web não encontrei ou não compreendi como poderia fazer isso... achei vários plugins que poderiam facilitar isso, inclusive utilizo o Bootstrap.Dialog, mas quando fica obsoleto tenho problemas na atualização, então eu gostaria de trabalhar mais com algo nativo do bootstrap mesmo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TESTE MODAL</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="confirma" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bootstrap-dialog-draggable" style="background: #f0ad4e; border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirma a gravação dos dados?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Texto</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="btn-nao" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <!--span class="bootstrap-dialog-button-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span-->
                            Não
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="btn-sim" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <!--span class="bootstrap-dialog-button-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span-->
                            Sim
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $(".btn-confirma").on("click", function () {

                    botao = $(this).prop("class").split(" ");

                    if (botao[1] === "btn1") {

                        $(".modal-body").html("Botão 1 clicado");
                    } else {

                        $(".modal-body").html("Botão 2 clicado");
                    }

                    $("#confirma").modal();
                });

                $("#btn-sim").on("click", function (e) {
                    alert("Quem clicou? \nBotão: " + botao[1]);
                    $("#btn-nao").click();
                });

            });

        </script>

        <div style="padding: 30px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <button class="btn-confirma btn1">Confirma 1</button>
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 30px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <button class="btn-confirma btn2">Confirma 2</button>
        </div>

        <script src="../../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente você deveria fazer tudo usando métodos do Bootstrap. Por exemplo, para abrir a modal, você usa os atributos `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma"` nos botões, e não capturando um clique para executar `$("#confirma").modal();` e abrir a modal.

Não é necessário nem classes nos botões, muito menos fazer `.split()` para pegar a segunda classe. Isso é <s>gambiarra</s> ruim e deixa seu código mais pesado e pode dar problema se você sem querer adicionar uma classe nos botões que não seja a que você esperava no split.

Uma forma simples de identificar o botão que irá abrir a modal é usar um atributo `data-*`, que pode ser `data-id`, com um valor para cada botão:

```
<button data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma">Confirma 1</button>

<button data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma">Confirma 2</button>
```

Cada botão tem seu `data-id` com seu valor (repare que não precisa de `class`, a não ser para estilizar os botões via CSS ou com classes nativas do Bootstrap).

O código JavaScript melhorado utilizando métodos do próprio Bootstrap está abaixo com explicações, e ainda evitando variáveis globais ou com escopo amplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#confirma').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { // executa quando a modal abrir
      var botao = $(e.relatedTarget).data("id"); // pega o data-id do botão clicado
      var body_html; // declara variável para criar o html
      if (botao === 1) {
         body_html = "Botão 1 clicado"; // cria o html para o botão 1
      } else if (botao === 2) {
         body_html = "Botão 2 clicado"; // cria o html para o botão 2
      }

      $(".modal-body").html(body_html); // insere o html no body da modal

      $("#btn-sim").one("click", function () { // cria uma evento de clique no botão "sim" que só funciona 1 vez
         alert("Quem clicou? \nBotão: " + botao);
         $("#confirma").modal("hide"); // esconde a modal
      });

   }).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) { // quando a modal fechar
      $("#btn-sim").off(); // cancela o evento clique no botão "sim"
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="confirma" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header bootstrap-dialog-draggable" style="background: #f0ad4e; border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Confirma a gravação dos dados?</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Texto</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" id="btn-nao" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                   <!--span class="bootstrap-dialog-button-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span-->
                   Não
               </button>
               <button type="button" id="btn-sim" class="btn btn-primary">
                   <!--span class="bootstrap-dialog-button-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span-->
                   Sim
               </button>
           </div>
       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div style="padding: 30px; margin: 0 auto;">
   <button data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma">Confirma 1</button>
</div>

<div style="padding: 30px; margin: 0 auto;">
   <button data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma">Confirma 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, deixa eu abusar da sua bondade... tem algum link que eu possa ver como "aninhar" modais? Tipo assim, vamos supor que o cara clicou em SIM então eu abriria outro modal (sem fechar a atual) com uma barra de progresso (um texto simples mesmo, "aguarde") e quando terminar o processo eu fecharia as modais. Minha ideia seria abrir nesse primeiro modal um formulario e assim que o cara confirmar eu abro outro pra ele esperar o processo terminar. Se preciso eu tento colocar um exemplo em outra pergunta.

Comment: Abrir duas modais ao mesmo tempo eu não sei se dá certo, creio até que não. Agora vc poderia tentar utilizar um sweetalert (plugin) ou mesmo alterando o corpo da modal aberta colocando a mensagem "Aguarde"..